# Boostrap Dual List Box

Tags: javascript, php

Buenos días, necesitaría saber por favor como pasar el resultado de las opciones elegidas en una doble lista bootstrap a una variable php para hacer POST a otra página.

```
 <div class="panel">
<form id="demoform" class="hide-list-label" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-title"> Dual Select Listbox </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body p25">
        <select class="demo1" multiple="multiple" size="10" name="demo1">
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
            <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
            <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
            <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
            <option value="option10">Option 10</option>
            <option value="option11">Option 11</option>
            <option value="option12">Option 12</option>
            <option value="option13">Option 13</option>
            <option value="option14">Option 14</option>
            <option value="option15">Option 15</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ph25">Submit Data</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
var demo1 = $('.demo1').bootstrapDualListbox({
    nonSelectedListLabel: 'Options',
    selectedListLabel: 'Selected',
    preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
    moveOnSelect: true,
    nonSelectedFilter: 'tion ([1-3]|[1][0-5])'
});

$("#demoform").submit(function() {
    alert("Options Selected: " + $('.demo1').val());
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: no manejo ese plugin. pero en ese caso, lo que me parece más funcional es que a medida que el usuario seleccione, tu registres esos valores en un input hidden que sea el que posteriormente vas a enviar. Pasar variables desde Javascript a php de otra forma no es posible. Avisame si esto responde tu pregunta. saludos.

Comment: Gracias por contestar. En caso de que selecciones una opción y te hayas equivocado, podrías "deseleccionarla"?

Comment: Claro. Vuelves a modificar el campo hidden. Lo que no manejo es el plugin que comentas, pero el caso es que, por cada cambio que se haga. capturas los datos, los separas por comas y se los pones en el value al input hidden. así siempre tendrás las últimas opciones seleccionadas. Si me sigues ?

Comment: Buenas @jrodriguez me funciona tal y como comentas. tengo que ponerlo como input hidden tal y como lo dices y al enviar, tanto si quitas como si pones, funciona. Muchas gracias.

Comment: A tu orden amigo, en ese caso marca mi comentario, para que quede como la respuesta que te fue útil y pueda cerrarse el post. Un saludo.

Comment: Hecho! Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el plugin `bootstrap-duallistbox` crea un nuevo `select` con el mismo nombre que el select original + `_helper{1,2}`. En tu caso:  `demo1_helper2` tendrá la lista de valores seleccionados (leer la [documentación](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) y el configuracion de `helperSelectNamePostfix`)

Una vez que realices el `POST` a tu script `PHP`, este recibirá estos valores en `$_POST['demo1_helper2']`.

Por ultimo, es importante fijarte que tu script `JS`, está evitando que se realice el POST a tu script, ya que retorna falso en cualquier caso. Para solventar esto, bastaría con sacar el `return false` del `submit`.

saludos

Comment: Funciona! muchas gracias Pablo